# Double sign a transaction, first on client, second on server

Tags: transactions, eosjs, dapp, signing

I am struggling with getting the following scenario to work, I want to create a transaction signed by two parties (not via the multisig contract, just a transaction with 2 signatures). One is the client, second is the server. The client part is figured out, I generate the transaction and sign it via 'scatter' and send it to my backend signed with the users signature. Now I want the server to do another sign off on that transaction and broadcast it to the network. So, the plan is this:

- sign by client via scattere
- send to backend
- sign by server
- broadcast to network

I have access to the eosjs libraries both on client and server to perform the signatures. I have searched the internet but have not found any answers yet.

Comment: What exact step is your question about? Signing by server?

Comment: The exact question is to have an action pushed with 2 authorizations, one from the client, and one from the server. As such the smart contract executing the action checks for the two permissions.

Comment: you would have to implement the contract-level signature-verification by yourself as there is only inbuild verification for the 'second'/'outer' signature.

At least it doesn't sound very clever to double verify the signatures. As you could verify the 'first' signature server-side and then sign and push a new transaction containing the 'first' signature, everything needed is on-chain and cryptographically approved. Everyone who ever wants to re-verify what you already verified, would be able to.

Comment: interesting approach you describe there @cmadh, essentially I check the signature of the transaction server side, and create a new transaction only signed with the server key and include proof that the first signature was valid. I will discuss if this is another viable option.

Comment: @cmadh the scenario here is with 2 different keys the signing process, thus one transaction being prepared, first signed with scatter, second signed by the server. I was re-reading your answer, and I believe there was some miscommunication there.

Comment: probably it's easier to understand if you tell more about what you want to achieve with this approach.

Comment: the use case here is I want to sign off / double check the provided parameters in the action. In this use case, we have two parties, one (the client) which is generating a transaction, and the second (the server) which validates some parameters of that transaction against some API and signs off on that transaction.

Answer (score 1):

You can sign everything you want using eosjs-ecc. 
See here [Github eosjs-ecc](https://github.com/EOSIO/eosjs-ecc)

```
ecc.Signature.signHash(sha256hash, private_key).toString()

ecc.sign(Buffer.from(data, 'utf8'), private_key)
```

But be aware, that the transaction always has to match with the ABI.

Comment: I am aware of the eosjs-ecc library. What I am looking for is to build a transaction signed by two parties, first a scatter user, and second a backend server.